# Ionic addRow & start is not defined

Tags: jquery, ionic-framework, ionic-view

Trying to figure out why I'm getting this error.

Loading page and login works, when I go to the next screen - "start" I get:

```
file:///:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined
    at file:///:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined
    at file:///:2
```

The template/ view is:

```
<ion-view title="Start" id="page23" style="background-color:#092652;">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header" ng-controller="startCtrl" ng-init="getEmployers()">
    <form ng-model="start" id="start-form14" class="list">
      <h1 id="start-heading11" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:300;text-align:center;" class="timer">00:00:00</h1>
      <label class="item item-select shallow shallow-white grey-bg" id="start-select9">
        <span class="input-label">Employer</span>
        <select id="selected_employer" ng-model="selected_employer" required>
          <option ng-repeat="d in demo_employers track"  value="{{d.employer_id}}" >{{d.employer_name}}</option>

        </select>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-select shallow shallow-white grey-bg" id="start-select10">
        <span class="input-label">{Cost Centre}</span>
        <select id="selected_costcentre" ng-model="selected_cc" required>
          <option    ng-repeat="costcentre in getCC(selected_employer)" value="{{costcentre.cc}}" >{{costcentre.cost_centre_name}}</option>

        </select>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-select shallow shallow-white grey-bg" id="start-select11">
        <span class="input-label">{Activity}</span>
        <select ng-controller="startCtrl" id="selected_activity" ng-model="selected_activity" ng-change="update()" required>
          <option  ng-repeat="activity in getActivities(selected_cc)" value="{{activity.activity_id}}"  >{{activity.activity}}</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <div>

        <a ng-controller="startCtrl" ng-click="start()" id="start-button14" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" style="border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px;" class="button button-balanced button-large button-block inactive"> Start Now</a>


      </div>
         </form>
    <div id="start-button-bar12" class="button-bar"></div>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I've tried some old solutions like checking for the '#/' instead of '/#/'.
I'm including jquery also. Any ideas why it might be acting up? :/

Thanks all

Comment: by chance did u find solution for this ?